# Radar plot peripheral labels cutoff

Tags: r, graphics, par, radar-chart

As you can see in this example, I'm trying to plot multiple radar charts. However, the peripheral axis labels are getting cutoff. I've tried specifying mar and oma in par, but haven't had any luck.

Can anyone else figure this out?

```
require(fmsb)

df <- data.frame(
  a = c(0.5, 0, 0.3),
  stopcuttingmeoff = c(1.2, 0, 0.5),
  c = c(0.25, 0, 0.1),
  d = c(0.25, 0, 0.1),
  dontcutmeoff = c(4, 0, 2))

par(mfrow=n2mfrow(4))
radarchart(df, axistype = 2, centerzero = TRUE, palcex = 0.9)
radarchart(df, axistype = 2, centerzero = TRUE, palcex = 0.9)
radarchart(df, axistype = 2, centerzero = TRUE, palcex = 0.9)
radarchart(df, axistype = 2, centerzero = TRUE, palcex = 0.9)
```

[image]

Comment: You say `mar` doesn't work, but you don't say why it doesn't work. Also, please indicate from where `radarchart` comes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A possible solution is using `xpd = TRUE` to prevent that the text is cut off at the margin. `fsmb::radarchart` internally uses `text` to add annotations, but unfortunately it does not allow you to pass parameters to `text` via `...`.

Therefore, you need to set the option globally:

```
par(xpd = TRUE, mfrow = c(2, 2), mar = c(2, 1, 2, 1))
radarchart(df, axistype = 2, centerzero = TRUE, palcex = 0.9)
radarchart(df, axistype = 2, centerzero = TRUE, palcex = 0.9)
radarchart(df, axistype = 2, centerzero = TRUE, palcex = 0.9)
radarchart(df, axistype = 2, centerzero = TRUE, palcex = 0.9)
```

Adjust `mar` to whatever values give you the desired margin on your device.